# Show that complex function with a maximum at two values has a maximum at an intermediate value

Tags: complex-analysis

> The function $f(z)$ is entire, and it is known that $\left|f(z)\right| < 1$ whenever $\left|z\right| = 1$ and that $\left|f(z)\right| < 10$ whenever $\left|z\right| = 10$. Show that $\left|f(z)\right| < 5$ whenever $\left|z\right| = 5$. What can be said about $\left|f(0)\right|$?

I'm not sure how to solve this. In my attempt I used the Cauchy Estimate to show that $\left|f'(1)\right| < 1$ and $\left|f'(10)\right|<1$. Now I'm trying to find a theorem or someway to show that $f'(z) < 1$ everywhere between $1$ and $10$ and thus the function grows at most linearly. Is this possible or am I going down the wrong path?

Comment: **Hint:** Consider the function $f(z)/z$. It's holomorphic away from the origin, and you have estimates on its size along the circles $|z|=1$ and $|z|=10$, so you should be able to conclude something about all the circles $|z|=r$ for $1<r<10$.

Comment: Also, for $f(0)$, you know by the maximum principle that $|f(0)|<1$, but a good question to ask is if $|f(0)|$ can be as close to $1$ as you like. For this, I suggest even just looking at linear polynomials $f(z) = a + bz$. Can you find examples of such functions where $|a|$ is very close to $1$ and $f$ satisfies the desired estimates?

Comment: @froggie $g(z):=f(z)/z $ if $ z\not= 0 $ and $ f'(0)$ if $ z=0$. Now this is holomorphic everywhere and the maximum modulus is $1$ for $|z|<=10$. Can you help me proceed from here ?

Comment: @SrinivasK: Actually, in some cases $g(z)$ won't be holomorphic at $0$, because it's possible that $f(0)\neq 0$. But nonetheless, $g(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}^*$. In particular, it is holomorphic on the annulus $1\leq |z|\leq 10$. And on both boundary circles of the annulus, we are given that $|g(z)|< 1$. Since this is true on the boundary of the annulus, the maximum principle should tell you it's true everywhere inside the annulus as well. In particular, $|g(z)|<1$ whenever $|z| = 5$, for instance.